# Performance measurement showing malloc impact per function call?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, malloc

my problem looks like this:
I have a function that parses a telegram, taking the biggest chunk of time in the total processing time for the contained data. I want to reduce the total processing time by reducing the cost for parsing the telegram. As the telegram requires a lot of string handling, I suspect that implied copying of strings while extracting information might be the the most likely source for this problem.

What I am looking for:
A tool - for an executable created on a Linux system from C++ source - that gives me the information on how much time is actually spent on malloc/free within the function that processes the telegram.
An ideal output would give me something like this:
- 10 ms spent on parseTelegram
-  5 ms spent on malloc/free (within parseTelegram)
I have used callgrind, but it doesn't seem to give me this information at the level of malloc/free.

The question I want to answer with an output like that:
Is it worth it to invest the - substantial - amount of time in removing implicit string copy within that parseTelegram function and/or use strings allocated from a pool.

Thanks for any hint on how to retrieve the information! It is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: You mentioned that you tried callgrind but it didn't give you the information that you were looking for. I would suggest giving it another try, as it is entirely capable of making the measurements that you described above. It's possible that you didn't have it configured properly.

Comment: Why do you use malloc/free at all, if it is C++ ? Or are you talking about mallocs/frees that happen "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Hi, do you have any hints on which option to use? When I look into the callgrind.out file, I see a couple of entries with malloc, but by far not enough to associate them with single functions.

Comment: I think you might be looking at this a little cockeyed. If your investigation finds that the string copy takes too long, who cares where in the string copy time is consumed unless you intend to rewrite the string copy routine? If you intend to reduce the running time by reducing the number of copies, where the copy is slow does not matter.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the malloc/free calls that are implicitly used for new/delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sampling profiler, like oprofile.
http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/about/

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned that I had used it previously as well. I have issues using it on our development servers though, as they are running on virtual machines. My recollection is that I would get the total amount of time spent on malloc/free, but not on a per calling function base. But it has been some years.

Answer (score 0):

gprof seems to be the choice. You can use it to determine which parts of a program are taking most of the execution time. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/

You simply have to add some flags to your compilator and you're ready to go!